# Arrayformula Looping Repetition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

For example I have this set of data below:

```
Header 1    Header 2
Mouse       5
Elephant    4
```

What I want to happen is for the word "Mouse" to repeat 5 times and the word "Elephant" to repeat 4 times from top to bottom in Column C.

The output will look something like this:

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3
Mouse       5           Mouse
Elephant    4           Mouse
                        Mouse
                        Mouse
                        Mouse
                        Elephant
                        Elephant
                        Elephant
                        Elephant
```

How to do this in Google Sheets?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below formula:

Assuming your data range is **A2:B** and you are entering the formula in **C2**, if not then you can change the range accordingly

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(A2:A&",", B2:B), ,999^99), ","))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your "Header 1" is in A1 and the rest of your posted sample is in A:B, place the following formula in C1 of an otherwise empty Column C:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header 3"; QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER(REPT(A2:A&"~",B2:B),A2:A<>""),"~",1,1)),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")})`

This formula will produce the header text (which you can change within the formula as you like) and all results.

`REPT` will repeat anything in A2:A (with a tilde appended to the end) B2:B times to form virtual single-cell strings.

`FILTER` will make sure only occupied rows are included in the `REPT` function.

`SPLIT` will split those repetitive strings into separate horizontal cells at those intermittent tildes.

`FLATTEN` will take all of the results of the `SPLIT` and form one column from them (spaces and all, since the number of cells per virtual row will differ depending on the requested number of repetitions).

`QUERY` will purge any empty rows that would have otherwise appeared in the `FLATTEN` results.

`ArrayFormula` is necessary because the formula is processing a range as opposed to a single row's data.